# Phonegap not copying the cordova file

Tags: javascript, cordova

Am trying to create an android phonegap project using the phonegap command line tools on windows.
I've set up my system with the correct environment variables after install the JDK and apache ant, the android sdk.
After run the create command out of androd\bin folder from the phonegap download on the command line. I get the following message

```
>     Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>     
>     Creating new android project... Copying template files... Copying js, jar & config.xml files... Copying cordova command tools...
> Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
```

But on browsing to the project folder the cordova and libs directories are empty, but looking at the sample that came in the download those folders are to contain files.
Why cant i find these files especially the cordova.jar and cordova.js, am doing something incorrectly? Please help